# ReactJS setInterval not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, electron, setinterval

I’m facing an issue with a timer that I want to establish in a react component but it’s giving me headache.

This is my current code:

```
const [dataStream, setDataStream] = useState(Array.from({ length: length }, (_, index) => yMin));
    const [chartValue, setChartValue] = useState(newValue)


    useEffect(() => {
        const timer1 = setInterval(() => {
            let value = chartValue;
            if (value > yMax) value = yMax;
            if (value < yMin) value = yMin;
            setDataStream(prevDataStream => [value, ...prevDataStream.slice(0, length - 1)]);
        }, interval);
    
        return function cleanup() {
            clearInterval(timer1);
        };
    }, [chartValue, yMax, yMin, length, interval]);
    

    useEffect(() => {
        setChartValue(newValue)
    }, [newValue]);
```

From the parent I‘m receiving a newValue state variable which is updating in irregular timespans.

Since I want to plot the data on a chart this would result in a „laggy“ appearance.

What I would like to do is establish a timer that takes my value and puts it ever .2 seconds (defined by my interval) into an array. This array will plot a line for my chart then.

I’m miserably failing at implementing this timer. Either I get errors cause the component re-renders the whole time, I have wrong or missing stuff in my dependency array, the timer only gets executed once, or my array is updated as soon as a newValue comes in, so it looks „laggy“.

Would be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Updating chartValue in the second useEffect as a dependency is probably the source of the lag, you should instead update it when the component mounts at the start.

This would mean you are not guaranteed an updated value of newValue in your main useEffect update loop. Thus, slightly change the callback for setDataStream, like so:
`setDataStream(prevDataStream => [chartValue, ...prevDataStream.slice(0, length - 1)]);`

This will remove the "lag" from constantly updating the chart, and should fix your problems.

```js
const [dataStream, setDataStream] = useState(Array.from({ length }, (_, index) => yMin));
  const [chartValue, setChartValue] = useState(newValue);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      // timer code goes here
      setDataStream(prevDataStream => [chartValue, ...prevDataStream.slice(0, length - 1)]);
    }, interval);

    return function cleanup() => {
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, [chartValue, length, yMax, yMin, interval]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setChartValue(newValue);
  }, []);
```

Comment: But wouldn't that mean, that my timer get's reset everytime a newValue arrives? newValue updates quiet quickly, I'd say less than 1ms. I want to use the timer to smooth the output. I think when newValue and therefore chartValue updates so often, it could cause issues with how the dependency arrays are set up here or not?

Comment: I suppose I could use 'useRef' on my newValue and pass it directly to the array. This way I'm not rerendering when newValue is changing and kill the interval of my timer when  new data slips in.

Comment: Yes, that would work. Sorry, I missed that part of your question! You would use something like `latestValue.current` and just grab that every time to pass into your array instead.